# Add class to views row if image fields has content

Tags: 7, theming, views

I have views which has multiple image fields. In some cases all those image fields are empty, but some cases one of them has content.

When image field has content I want to have extra class .has-image for views row.

There is image fields: image_field_1, image_field_2 and image_field_3

It can be done programmatically, but I'm lost how to check those fields.
I know this much:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars){
```

**SOLUTION**

There can not be used `$vars['classes_array'][$id][]` because `$classes_array[$id]` is not an array.

Here is code for working solution.

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $rows = $vars['rows'];

foreach ($vars['view']->result as $id => $row) {

    if (!empty($row->field_field_image) || !empty($row->field_field_image_2) || !empty($row->field_field_image_3)) {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] .= ' has_field';
    }  
    else {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] .= ' has_no_field';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: assuming the class only affects the images, why not just include the row class under settings, regardless of whether or not there is an image present?

Comment: Nope. I'm trying to make this and seems that it is not possible without creating extra class for those views rows which has image:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991350/center-div-vertically-when-img-tag-is-not-displayed

Comment: see if this helps (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/dynamically-adding-a-css-class-to-a-view-row-with-template-php)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the preprocess function you find the result in

```
$vars['view']->result
```

and the corresponding classes array under

```
$vars['classes_array']
```

where in results and in classes array the corresponding rows have the same key.

You can do now something like this in your preprocess function:

```
foreach ($vars['view']->result as $rid => $row) {
  if (isset($row->YOUR_FIELD) && !empty($row->YOUR_FIELD)) {
    $vars['classes_array'][$rid][] = 'has_field';
  }  
  else {
    $vars['classes_array'][$rid][] = 'has_no_field';
  }
}
```

It is untested and just a little scribble but maybe it helps you.

Comment: I'm getting: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in. Any help?

Comment: I got it work by using this, but now it adds same class (has_field) to every row even if field_image has content or does not have : `function theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) { $view = $vars['view']; $rows = $vars['rows']; foreach ($vars['view']->result as $id => $row) { if (isset($row->field_image)) { $vars['classes_array'][$id] = 'has_field'; } else { $vars['classes_array'][$id] = 'has_no_field'; } } }`

Comment: Hmm, could it be because I use one field to show all content. So I have field which has Rewrite results and then tokens. So it basically loads all fields no matter if they does not have content? Here is my field Rewrite results: `<div class="front_tile_overlay"></div><div class="tile_image">[field_image][field_image_2][field_image_3]</div><div class="tile_content"><div class="front_tile_title">[field_tile_title]</div><div class="front_tile_body">[field_text_to_frontpage_box]</div></div>`

Comment: So code should check if field has value (content) or not. Any tips?

Comment: Do you use devel module? There is a function `dpm()` which shows you the content of an array or anything else. Maybe add `dpm($vars['view']->result); ` to your preprocess function to find out how the field looks like when there is content and when there is no content.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to using a preprocess function (because I wanted to override this in a module not the theme and didn't want to delve into the possibility of overriding the theme registry), I did the following:

1. created a custom version of the view's theme template **Style Output**: `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`, by removing the div wrapper within the foreach loop
2. created a custom version of **Row style** output: `views-view-fields.tpl.php` by wrapping the fields with a div there and adding class names based on the field data in `$row->field_YOUR_FIELDNAME[0]['raw']['value']`

I had a boolean field I was checking, so you may want to log (with watchdog) or print out `$row->field_YOUR_FIELDNAME[0]`
and see what's available.