# Unique Classes on lists items

Tags: views, theming, 8

I'm very new to Drupal 8 theming and I'm trying to replicate a random website to practice.

I have a problem recreating this part though:

[image]

I have a block with the latest news articles and a block with most popular.

**I wonder if I could put unique classes on each item in the list (of latest news)**, that way I can make the widths different and make the floats work.

Is there anyway to do this? If I'm doing this wrong and there's a better way, feel free to tell me!

Comment: Please have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You cannot ask about _Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided_. So update your question to include some relevant code or a screnshot of your view.

Comment: @Neograph734 not asking anyone to build a code from scratch. Just wondering if it is possible and where I should look for it.

Comment: I'd create separate blocks and use the pagination function. Top post should have pager offset 0, show 1. And then for the 2 post block use offset 1 show 2. And for the 4 posts use offset 3, show 4. Much easier then attempting to set a class per row.

Comment: For setting a class per row, have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/dynamically-adding-a-css-class-to-a-view-row-with-template-php

Comment: @Neograph734 : why don't you add a real answer to replace your last 2 comments? Seems like they do make a lot of sense ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I hadn't because it would not answer the question `Unique Classes on lists items`. But since it does help the OP, I might :)

Comment: Well, then consider an answer like "even though it may not be a complete solution for your question, you may want to consider so and so as an alternative, or something that partially helps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replicate the desired behavior you can create several Views blocks and use the pager `Display a specified number of items` option. Then for each block change the amount and offset:

[image: pager options]

If you would do this with 3 different blocks and use offset/amounts of 0/1, 1/2 and 3/4 you should be able to stack them and have the desired result.

If you really really want to change the class per row, have a look at the great example [Dynamically adding a CSS class to a view row with template.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/dynamically-adding-a-css-class-to-a-view-row-with-template-php) where you can use a views preprocessor to set the right class per row.